# Is it possible to develop Android Applications without an IDE and with a very low grade laptop?

Tags: android, sdk, ide

This question has been asked before but I cannot seem to find either YES or NO.

I am fairly a noob when it comes to app development and I can only work with Pascal, and Delphi 2010 is the only IDE my laptop can run without trouble.  I have a **Compaq CQ58 notebook pc, wth a Intel(R) celeron(R) 1000M @ 1.8 GHz processor** 64 bit os and **2 GB RAM**.

It is a very low grade laptop, but is it still possible to develop android apps with it? I have **Kotlin's IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.2.1** insalled but it takes up too much RAM with the Gradle plugin running.

To sum it all up, can an Android app be developed **Without an IDE** and if so, HOW?

Comment: your problems go further than this, because let's imagine you build the app without using an ide and manually run gradle and every script required, how do you plan to debug ? this is probably an unrealistic approach

Answer (score 0):

Without an IDE?  Yes.  You can use command line gradle commands to compile, and any text editor to write the files-  vi or notepad would work.  With that low a grade laptop?  Gradle is memory hungry.  I wouldn't want to compile a non-trivial app on less than 16 GB, and I prefer 32 or 64.  The speed of your processor is actually less important than being able to hold enough data in memory for gradle to run.

I don't know where you are in the world, but you can get a cheap PC for only a few hundred dollars.  If you can possibly afford it, its well worth the investment.  Even if you could build on your laptop, builds would take hours as things paged.  2GB has been the minimum settings for most OS for a decade, and it didn't run well in that.  You can get a 16 GB machine, which I would consider the minimum, for $500 or less.  You don't need a good video card or the fastest processor, but you do need sufficient ram.

Comment: you could, in theory, probably just write code and push all of it to a build server, that will probably reduce the need for having to build and run gradle locally, up to a certain extent, right ? this is all a very long and complicated path though

Comment: @a_local_nobody True, you could.  But I'm going to assume someone trying to do it on this level of machine doesn't have access to a build server.

Comment: yeah, i thought this question was interesting to an extent, the amount of knowledge you'd need to make this possible would probably make it borderline impossible for anyone starting out, which leaves the most simple approach as the answer, to get a new laptop